# asynchronously use window.open in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser, tabs

I have the following code that when the user presses the button in the form below it makes a server request and accordingly open a new tab or display an error

```
     search() {
        const serial = this.searchForm.get('searchValue').value;
        this.service.check(serial)
            .subscribe(resp => {
                if (resp) {
                    this.denied = false;
                    window.open(`/path?serial=${serial}`);
                } else {
                    this.denied = true; //display error in the HTML
                }
            });
      }
```

and the form (modified) like:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="search()" [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input formControlName="searchValue">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

The issue (as expected) is that browsers will not allow `window.open` unless authorized by the user.

Is there any workaround around that? Maybe some refactoring of my code? A manipulation of the workflow?

P.S: I do not want to do:

```
newTab = window.open();
this.service.check(serial)
    .subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp) {
            this.denied = false;
            newTab.location.href = `/path?serial=${serial}`;
            ....
```

since it is not sure whether the service will respond with true or false.

Comment: Have you tried maybe adding a hidden link or button and triggering the click event via code?

Comment: @itdoesntwork, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that indeed, but it has the same effect, unfortunately.